# Replace null check with Optional

Tags: java

I would like to know since i'm fan of java 14 if replacing null checks with Optional.ofNullable
is safe for this language. I know a simple null check doesn't cost any memory while new creating new objects like optional cost but i guess it has zero performance impact or memory impact. Can someone enlight me?

The code for my game was like:

```
if (item!= null)
{
   if (item.getCrystal() == Crystal.A)
   {
     player.getInventory().addItem(inventoryItem);
   }
}
```

to something which i enjoy and i find cool

```
Optional.ofNullable(item).filter(i -> i.getCrystal() == Crystal.A).ifPresent(k -> player.getInventory.addItem(i));
```

Can someone enlight me that i'm ok with it? Maybe is cool but cost a lot? I don't know.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: some people find this abusing, some (like me) like it. it's so much easier for me to read such code, but that is, of course, subjective.

Comment: I definitely prefer your second approach.  Optional can certainly make code easier to read.  Some things to consider, though: 1) I would split the line so each method is on it's own line (like each line starts with a `.`).  This way you don't get super long one-liners that are impossible to read. 2) You might consider making `item` an Optional further up the line, so it's already an Optional when it hits this part of the code. (This could depend on the structure of your code) 3) I might drop the `filter()` and use a traditional if statement for clarity, purely personal preference.

Comment: And to answer your actual question, yes, wrapping a field into an object has some memory and performance overhead.  But the effect is quite minimal.  You should program for clarity, and if performance becomes an issue, work from there.  With modern computers, memory is pretty much never a problem, I wouldn't even spend brain cell time thinking about it (the exception being memory leaks).

Comment: As i said to the other guy, we speak for 2.500 players this can happen 2.500 times in couple of minutes. Would this affect my performance?

Comment: Sure, initializing 2500 optionals could be a performance hit.  But we can't say for sure how this will affect your given program.  My response is still: do whatever makes the code more clear.  If you're playing the game later on and you notice it's a bit slow in this area, you can get rid of the optionals quite easily.  On the other hand, if you leave spaghetti code in there, and you find your game has a bug in it, but you look back at this piece of this code 5 years from now and you have no clue what it does, now you're stuck.  Always program for readability.

Comment: Get a profiler, everything else is guessing :-)

Comment: I believe this is not an appropriate use of Optional.  A better design is to make `item` an Optional instance to begin with, or if possible, write the code so `item` is never null.

Comment: The conventional wisdom is that, in Java, the `Optional<T>` type should be used as a method return type, to strongly indicate to a client user that the method may not be able to return a value and that he should therefore check whether this is so.  Other uses of `Optional` may well be a code smell, but there are, perhaps, a few other legitimate use cases.  I agree that your use of Optional to check for a null return value is actually less readable than an explicit null check.

Comment: Creating 2,500 Optional's is something that you could easily test. I don't think you'd notice the overhead unless you were running on a computer that used vacuum tubes. 2,500,000, maybe.

Answer (score 1):

In simple cases like this, the just in time compiler can likely elide the object allocation, or at least allocate it on the stack, so the overhead is negligible.

Here's a small benchmark:

```
public abstract class Benchmark {

    final String name;

    public Benchmark(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + "\t" + time() + " ns / iteration";
    }

    private BigDecimal time() {
        try {
            // automatically detect a reasonable iteration count (and trigger just in time compilation of the code under test)
            int iterations;
            long duration = 0;
            for (iterations = 1; iterations < 1_000_000_000 && duration < 1_000_000_000; iterations *= 2) {
                long start = System.nanoTime();
                run(iterations);
                duration = System.nanoTime() - start;
                cleanup();
            }
            return new BigDecimal((duration) * 1000 / iterations).movePointLeft(3);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Executes the code under test.
     * @param iterations
     *            number of iterations to perform
     * @return any value that requires the entire code to be executed (to
     *         prevent dead code elimination by the just in time compiler)
     * @throws Throwable
     *             if the test could not complete successfully
     */
    protected abstract Object run(int iterations) throws Throwable;
    
    /**
     * Cleans up after a run, setting the stage for the next.
     */
    protected void cleanup() {
        // do nothing
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Integer[] a = {null, -1, null, 1}; // mix nulls and real values
        
        System.out.println(new Benchmark("Optional") {
            @Override
            protected Object run(int iterations) throws Throwable {
                int[] sum = {0};
                for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
                    Optional.ofNullable(a[i & 3]).filter(k -> k > 0).ifPresent(k -> sum[0] += k);
                }
                return sum[0]; 
            }
        });
        System.out.println(new Benchmark("if != null") {
            @Override
            protected Object run(int iterations) throws Throwable {
                int[] sum = {0};
                for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
                    var k = a[i & 3];
                    if (k != null && k % 2 != 0) {
                        sum[0] += k; 
                    }
                }
                return sum[0]; 
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This shows that the overhead of using an `Optional` is about 1 ns, i.e. a modern CPU can construct and evaluate about 1 billion `Optional` objects per second. In all but the most extreme and contrived of workloads, the use of `Optional` will not affect performance enough for humans to notice.

The decision to use `Optional` should therefore not be guided by performance considerations, but by which version allows yourself to express yourself more clearly and simply.

In this case, I'd argue that the if statement is actually more readable. Sure, you've squashed everything onto a single line, but you could do the same with an if statement:

```
if (item != null && item.getCrystal() == Crystal.A) player.getInventory().addItem(inventoryItem);
```

If you do that, you'll notice that the if statement is actually shorter and more to the point than your version:

```
Optional.ofNullable(item).filter(i -> i.getCrystal() == Crystal.A).ifPresent(k -> player.getInventory.addItem(i));
```

Of course, in real code you'll probably want to keep your lines reasonably short, so the comparison is

```
if (item != null && item.getCrystal() == Crystal.A) {
    player.getInventory().addItem(inventoryItem);
}
```

vs

```
Optional.ofNullable(item).filter(i -> i.getCrystal() == Crystal.A)
    .ifPresent(k -> player.getInventory.addItem(i));
```

Again, I find the first version more readable, because it contains fewer words.

Comment: I just enjoy coding like this but when it come to a game that this happen on each player and we speak for 2.500 players this can happen 2.500 times in couple of minutes. Would this affect my performance? Or java and modern machines doesn't care in 2020 ?

Comment: Potentially it could affect performance.  Creating extra objects (The `Optional`) is not free.  I've measured it in microbenchmarks and there the speed change is very noticeable.  However in real code the change in speed might be negligible.  Only way to know for sure is measure actual performance in real code, and there the rule is "premature optimization is the root of all evil."

Comment: I just did a test and null is like 0.006 nanosecond while Optional is 0.7 nanosecond to 1.5 millisecond (if not initialized i guess?)

Comment: @TheLegendBeginsTremors: My guess is that the difference is not nearly that large.  You're talking, like, 2 orders of magnitude which is suspect.  More likely is that you did not properly use a microbenchmarking test harness.

Comment: @TheLegendBeginsTremors: 1.5 ms is over a million cpu cycles. It is wholly implausible that the construction and evaluation of an Optional could take this long. My tests indicate about 1 ns, with a little variance depending on how often the value is null.